# Mongodb search and filter in nested array data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, filter, unique

I want to filter the array and get all the results while querying

```
[{
    "college_id" : 25,
    "name" : "IIT",
    "city" : "Delhi",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "engineering",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Electrical Engineering)",
                            "fees" : 20000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "course_type" : "Master of Technology [M.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master of Technology [M.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "24"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master of Technology [M.Tech] (Electrical Engineering)",
                            "fees" : 20000,
                            "duration" : "24"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "college_id" : 75,
    "name" : "NIT",
    "city" : "Kolkata",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "engineering",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Electrical Engineering)",
                            "fees" : 20000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "discipline_name" : "management",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA] (Finance)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA] (Marketing)",
                            "fees" : 20000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Questions:
1. Find where fees is greater than 30000.
Output should be:**

```
[{
    "college_id" : 25,
    "name" : "IIT",
    "city" : "Delhi",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "engineering",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "course_type" : "Master of Technology [M.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master of Technology [M.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "24"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "college_id" : 75,
    "name" : "NIT",
    "city" : "Kolkata",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "engineering",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Bachelor of Technology [B.Tech] (Biotechnology)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "discipline_name" : "management",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA] (Finance)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

**2. Find where fees is greater than 30000 and less than 50000 and ‘course_type’ is ‘Master in Business Administration [MBA]’**
*Sample output*

```
[{
    "college_id" : 75,
    "name" : "NIT",
    "city" : "Kolkata",
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "management",
            "course_list" : [ 
                {
                    "course_type" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA]",
                    "program_name_list" : [ 
                        {
                            "program_name" : "Master in Business Administration [MBA] (Finance)",
                            "fees" : 40000,
                            "duration" : "48"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work?

Comment: db.college.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         courses: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$courses",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.discipline_name", "management" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])

i am getting result of 1st nested. when applying 2nd one eg: course_list is  not working

Comment: Can you please update your question to include those details? The more detailed your question and more information you provide, the better others can understand what you're doing, what has worked, what hasn't, what you're expecting to happen, etc, and are then better able to help you. In this format, it appears as you've copied and pasted some homework questions with no background or explanation. The chances of someone doing your work for you on this site are slim, so your best option to get good answers is to rework your question into a great question that will benefit others as well.